# Setting background image for itempage.xaml

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

I'm developing windows phone 8.1 app and when I set the background image for the hubpage.xaml it doesn't affect itempage.xaml. Can anyone help me set the same background for all the other pages in the app? I'm using a hub template anyway.

Answer (score 2):

That's because the properties on your xaml are page-specific.
If you want to use the same background, you could either manually assign each page a background in your xaml (see the `Background` property of HubPage.xaml's `Hub` section.

Or you could override your `ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush` and set it to the background you want.
Edit your App.xaml and add a new entry to the `ResourceDictionary`.

```
<ResourceDictionary x:Key="Default">
    <ImageBrush x:Key="HubBackgroundImageBrush" ImageSource="Assets/HubBackground.png"/>
    <ImageBrush x:Key="ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush" ImageSource="Assets/HubBackground.png"/>
</ResourceDictionary>
```